# How to set a pandas column conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

After reading a few other Stackoverflow articles on the topic I came up with the following code, but I keep getting errors.

```
df6['Accepted'] = np.where((df6['Status'] == 'Admitted' or df6['Status'] ==
'Admitted from WL' or df6['Status'] == 'Matriculating'), '1', '0')
```

I also tried using the following instead of the "ors":

```
df6['Status'] in ['Admitted' , 'Admitted from WL', 'Matriculating']
```

This did not work either

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
exec(open("C:\\python\\xxxxxx\\Analysis\\clean_data_v6.py").read())
File "<string>", line 110, in <module>
File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site
packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
(df6['Status'] == 'Admitted' or df6['Status'] == 'Admitted from WL' or df6['Status'] == 'Matriculating')
```

You'd need this:

```
(df6['Status'] == 'Admitted') | (df6['Status'] == 'Admitted from WL') | (df6['Status'] == 'Matriculating')
```

Or easier:

```
df6.Status.isin(['Admitted' , 'Admitted from WL', 'Matriculating'])
```